# NFS: Network disconnect causes Gnome Nautilus to hang / Jumping progress bars

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, mount, nfs

I mount NFSv4 export via /etc/fstab and mount and use the shared folder in nautilus.

There are two issues:

- When I copy a large file (around 4 GB) to the NFS server, the progress bar rapidly goes to 2 GB and then basically stops moving. But the copy s still in progress - it is just not displayed well
- When I disconnect from the network without unmounting the nfs share, nautilus freezes.

How can I work around that?

`/etc/export` on the server

```
/export/share   192.168.0.0/24(rw,sync,insecure,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

`/etc/fstab` on the client:

```
server:/share   /mnt    nfs4    soft,tcp
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have the first problem reported, but no answer for it. The copy also tends to lock up other parts of the system (perhaps due to Nautilus' ubiquity as a GNOME service) while the copy goes on.

On the second point, I found this SO question very useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40317/91808.  In particular the `umount -f /mnt/nfs` suggestion worked for me when nothing else did, saving me from an irritating reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I would use automount. It mounts/unmounts the share automatically when it is accessed/not accessed. I don't think it will affect the progress bar problem but it should fix the freezes.

Have a look at [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/462878/151431) (specifically, steps 5-7) for more information on how to set it up.

---

UPDATE

I found that the file manager will hang if the shared volumes are linked to (or directly mounted) in my home directory. By placing links to my mountpoints in a *sub* directory of `$HOME` I had no more freezes.

The problem is that `autofs` will mount the share each time it is accessed, that includes `ls`. So, every time you open nautilus and you have the mount linked to or mounted in your $HOME, it tries to mount it and hangs.

So, my current (hang-free) settings are:

1. NFS share mounted at /mnt/shared/movies
2. It is linked to in a sub directory of my $HOME:

   ```
   $ ls $HOME | grep shared
   shared
   $ ls -l $HOME/shared
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 20 Feb 15  2012 movies -> /mnt/shared/movies
   ```

This way, the volume will only be mounted if I do an `ls $HOME/shared` and not a simple `ls $HOME`.

Finally, **make sure you are using the -soft option**.

Comment: Nope, not working here. I managed to configure autofs and it automatically mounted the share, but if I disconnect the network. Nothing is unmounted and if I click on a file in the share, nautilus freezes.

Comment: @Alex, see updated answer.

Comment: I am having the soft option in the /etc/auto.server file and my share is not mounted to $HOME - it is mounted in /mnt. Still, when I have the share open and disconnect, everything hangs.

Comment: @Alex and it is not linked to anywhere else?

Comment: No it is not - mount shows only this one connection managed by autofs

Comment: @Alex I know, I am asking whether you are linking the mount to anywhere in your $HOME using  `ln -s` or similar. If not, I have no idea why you are having problems, I used to have the same issue and fixed it as I describe in my answer.

Comment: nope I do not link it anywhere else.

Comment: @Alex, Even with my solution nautilus will freeze when you click on a share that is no longer available. Clicking on it will cause the automount daemon to attempt to mount it and nautilus will wait for a response. When using automount, you avoid having nautilus free even _without_ clicking on any share of the mount which is what happens when not using automount.